# Get C# 7.3 listed in VS 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to set my project to use C# v7.3, but I am not able to get that version in to my language version list

[image]

**I've got all these installed**

[image]

I must be missing something obvious?!

Comment: Yes, you don't have version 15.7 or greater

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto version 15.7 of?

Comment: VS 2017 is named 15. You need update 7 or greater, hence 15.7 or greater

Comment: Perfect! I haven't updated VS in a while.. Thank you.

Comment: The Langauge version is a Compiler feature, **not** a Framework one. Do not worry, you are not the first one to confuse those today.

Comment: @Christopher You are right, I should've known better. Thank you though!